# What is Blackheart’s participation in Infinity War in comics?

Tags: marvel, comics

Blackheart was portrayed in several video games related to the Infinity War storyline; [Marvel Super Heroes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Super_Heroes_(video_game)) and [Marvel Super Heroes: War of the Gems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Super_Heroes_in_War_of_the_Gems).

How does Blackheart fit in the *Infinity War* story in comics? What's his participation?

Comment: Totally absent, if memory serves

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blackheart does not appear in the six-issue *[Infinity
War](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Infinity_War_Vol_1)* miniseries (1992), nor in any of the tie-in issues in other titles, as far as I can tell.

Note that his entry in the *[Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe Master Edition #34](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_Master_Edition_Vol_1_34)* (1993) does not list the *Infinity
War* miniseries or any of its tie-ins among his appearances.

> Significant issues: DAREDEVIL #270 (created by Mephisto; battled Daredevil and Spider-Man); DAREDEVIL#278-282 (alongside Mephisto, battled Daredevil, Gorgon, Karnak, Number 9, and Silver Surfer); HEART OF DARKNESS (sent to earth with diminished powers by Mephisto to learn humility; battled Ghost Rider II, the Punisher, and Wolverine); WONDER MAN #22 (alongside the Grim Reaper, brought Wonder Man to Mephisto's realm to battle Mephisto)
>
> [image]
>
> <sub>*Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe Master Edition #34* (September, 1993)</sub>

The *[Daredevil](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Daredevil_Vol_1)* issues (1989-1990) and *[Ghost Rider/Wolverine/Punisher: Hearts of Darkness #1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Ghost_Rider/Wolverine/Punisher:_Hearts_of_Darkness_Vol_1_1)* (1991) were all published prior to *Infinity War* (1992), whereas *[Wonder Man Vol. 2 #22](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Wonder_Man_Vol_2_22)* (1993) was published afterwards, so this list of appearances skips right over the *Infinity War* event (1992).